# Object member variable updating in function but not persisting

Tags: c++, vector

I am fairly new to c++ and building a simple battleship game. I have a function that initializes the ship types and lengths by taking in a vector of ship objects. I have confirmed that the type and ship length are updating inside the function but the changes are not persisting in the main function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "ships.h"
#include "board.h"
#include "player.h"


using std::vector; 

void initialize_ships(vector<ship> &newFleet)
{
    vector<string> ship_types = { "carrier","battleship","submarine","cruiser","destroyer" };

    for (auto ii = 0; ii != newFleet.size(); ++ii)
    {
        newFleet[ii].type = ship_types[ii];
        newFleet[ii].setLength();
        if (newFleet[ii].type == "carrier")
        {
            std::cout << "Carrier in function has type: " << newFleet[ii].type << std::endl;
        }

    }
}

int main()
{


ship player_carrier, player_battleship, player_submarine, player_cruiser, player_destroyer;
vector<ship> player_fleet = {player_carrier, player_battleship, player_submarine, player_cruiser, player_destroyer };


initialize_ships(player_fleet);
std::cout << "Carrier in main has type: " << player_carrier.type << std::endl;



system("pause");
return 0; 

}

#ifndef  SHIPS_H
#define SHIPS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using std::string;

struct ship
{
    // ships member variables 
    int len;
    char dir; 
    int health; 
    int row;
    int col;
    char symb;
    string type; 

    void setLength()
    {
        if (type == "carrier")
        {
            len = 5;
        }
        else if (type == "battleship")
        {
            len = 4;
        }
        else if (type == "cruiser")
        {
            len = 3;
        }
        else if (type == "submarine")
        {
            len = 3;
        }
        else if (type == "destroyer")
        {
            len = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid ship type!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

#endif //  SHIPS_H
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a [mcve].  As is the code you've posted should work.

Comment: 1) Please provide [mcve]. 2) How are you checking, that the changes aren't persisted?

Comment: *but the changes are not persisting in the main function.* -- How are you determining that the changes are not persisting?  A `vector` stores copies of what you put into it, not references or pointers to what you're placing inside of vector.

Comment: Are you saying that the `vector` doesn't change in main? Or the actual local ship objects you've declared? If you want the latter, you'll need `player_fleet` to be a `vector<ship&>`

Comment: I've updated to include all the code necessary to replicate my error. Carrier in function gives type "carrier", while in int main() it gives no type as if it has not been initialized.

Comment: `vector<ship> player_fleet = {player_carrier` fills the `vector` with *copies*  of the original objects - only the copies in that vector get modified

Comment: Thanks @UnholySheep. This explanation reminded me of this fact. The issue was corrected by creating a vector of pointers `vector<ship *> player_fleet = {&player_carrier,...}` and then dereferencing each pointer in the function. I'm sure this isn't the best way to do this but it works for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally making copies is a common reason for changes to be “lost”.  For this particular situation, where you want to have objects in a container *and* have names for those objects (as if they were members of a class), the sensible thing to do is to make **references** to objects in the container:

```
vector<ship> player_fleet(5);
ship &player_carrier=player_fleet[0],
  &player_battleship=player_fleet[1],
  &player_submarine=player_fleet[2],
  &player_cruiser=player_fleet[3],
  &player_destroyer=player_fleet[4];
```

Be careful not to cause the `vector` to reallocate, since that would invalidate your references.  (Of course, if it never changes size, `ship player_fleet[5];` would suffice.)